# Explain these parts of the code for me please

Tags: java, stack

I need to check for balanced expressions in a entered string.
I get how most of the java code works by reading the guides where i found the code and a few youtube videos.
but some parts of it still i dont get i added comments to those parts.

```
package homework;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class homewokr2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("enter code for which to check if expression is balanced ");
        
        String code = myScan.next();
    
         String checkBalancedExpr1=checkBalancedParentesis("" +code);
         System.out.println(""+checkBalancedExpr1);
    
         myScan.close();
 }
 public static String checkBalancedParentesis(String expr)
 {
 if (expr.isEmpty())    *// why is it (expr) should it not be (stack.isEmpty)?*
 return "Balanced";
 Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
 for (int i = 0; i < expr.length(); i++)
 {
 char current = expr.charAt(i);
 if (current == '{' || current == '(' || current == '[')
 {
 stack.push(current);
 }
 if (current == '}' || current == ')' || current == ']')
 {
 if (stack.isEmpty())
 return "Not Balanced";
 char last = stack.peek();
 if (current == '}' && last == '{' || current == ')' && last == '(' || current == ']' && last == '[')
 stack.pop();
 else 
 return "Not Balanced";
 }
 }
 return stack.isEmpty()?"Balanced":"Not Balanced"; // i dont rly get this part of it
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `if (expr.isEmpty())    *// why is it (expr) should it not be (stack.isEmpty)?* return "Balanced";`

This is just checking an edge condition: If you call this method with a completely empty string, it's obviously balanced. That's all this is doing.

It's also entirely unneccessary: If you remove that code it still works just the same: After all, then there are 0 expressions, therefore the main for loop (that loops through each character in the input string) would loop 0 times (hey, empty string, no characters, so no looping), and therefore stack would obviously be empty, which returns 'balanced'.

> `return stack.isEmpty()?"Balanced":"Not Balanced"; // i dont rly get this part of it`

If the stack object (which represents... a stack, hence the name) is empty, then it was balanced. If after going through every character there's still something on there then it wasn't. Here, trivial example:

Given input `(hello()`, then...

the for loop thing runs 8 times; once for each character. The first time it runs, it sees the first `(` and puts it on the stack. The second time it runs, it sees the second `(` and puts that on the stack; now the stack is `['(', '(']`. The next 5 times it runs it sees 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', and 'o' which all are completely ignored and have no effect. The 8th time it runs, it sees ')' which matches as the closing equivalent to what's on top of the stack right now (top of stack = `stack.peek()`), and thus the stack is popped: the top of it is removed, and now the stack is back down to simply being `['(']`.

Now the loop ends as we ran out of characters. Given that the stack isn't empty, it's unbalanced, and that is returned.